# Remove trailing white spaces,unicode characters and a special character

Tags: python, python-unicode, removing-whitespace, unicode-string

How to clean a string from white spaces and a special character in python.

I am scraping some data however the text am getting is a little gibberish. I figure i could clean using `join` `strip` and `enconding` however my output is unexpected.

```
#cleaner function

def string_cleaner(rouge_text):
             return (" ".join(rouge_text.strip()).encode('ascii', 'ignore').decode("utf-8")).replace("\\","")

print(string_cleaner("\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t Nokia 9 PureView- 5.99\ "))
print(string_cleaner("\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\tMi Electronic Scooter\uff08Black\uff09EU\t \t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t "))
```

**OUTPUT**

[image: screenshot]

> How do i clean my string and get normal text?

Comment: Did you mean `rouge_text.split()` ?

Comment: if i used `split` without changing the code it could have worked also.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure I get what you mean by "clean my string and get normal text", but maybe try to use is this way:

```
def string_cleaner(rouge_text):
    # "" instead of " " in .join() method
    return ("".join(rouge_text.strip()).encode('ascii', 'ignore').decode("utf-8")).replace("\\","")

print(string_cleaner("\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t Nokia 9 PureView- 5.99\ "))
print(string_cleaner("\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\tMi Electronic Scooter\uff08Black\uff09EU\t \t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t "))
```

#### OUTPUT:

```
>>> print(string_cleaner("\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t Nokia 9 PureView- 5.99\ "))
Nokia 9 PureView- 5.99
>>> print(string_cleaner("\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\tMi Electronic Scooter\uff08Black\uff09EU\t \t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t "))
Mi Electronic ScooterBlackEU
```

Comment: Yeah  i meant without the huge spacing. Worked.